# AngularJs - stateProvider to reloading controller when page refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state that links to a different page and a different controller, like this:

```
.state('productEdit', {
                url: '/productEdit/:id',
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/products/editProduct.cshtml',
                controller: 'app.views.products.editProduct',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
```

The problem is, when I go to this page or refresh the linked page, the controller doesn't initialize again, so the variables get "stuck", even when I clean the cache.

I'm using ui-sref like this:

```
          <div ng-repeat="product in vm.products" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" >
                <a ui-sref="productEdit({id: product.id})">
                    <div style="padding:5px">
                        <div class="card-product">
                            <h4>
                                {{product.name}}
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                {{product.description}}
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </a>
             </div>
```

Any one knows how I can make the controller reload every time the page is reached?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use ui-router, according to documentation you can pass optional configuration to ui-sref, in your case should be similar to

```
<a ui-sref="productEdit({id: product.id})"  ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">
                    <div style="padding:5px">
                        <div class="card-product">
                            <h4>
                                {{product.name}}
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                {{product.description}}
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </a>
```

Comment: I tried this and also the reload: true option. None of these work.

Comment: Tried even with 
down vote
accepted
This solution works in AngularJS V.1.2.2:

$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
}); ? Obviously it is possible only from controller

Comment: I tried and still didn't work. Like this: vm.lk = function () {
                $state.transitionTo('productEdit', { 'id': 1 }, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true });
            }  and called this function with ng-click

Comment: Try to add in state definition cache: false

Comment: I think I solved the problem, the controller was failling to load a dependency but the error wasn't being showed for some reason. Thanks for the help!